# How Can I Make a New Mesh From the Highest Points of Other Meshes?

Tags: modeling, topology, 3d-printing, remesh

I'm trying to take a messy model of a map I found online and convert it into something 3d-printable. I have tried welding all the parts etc. and come to the conclusion that I am wasting my time. My question is:

Is there a way to make a new mesh from the highest points of all these messy meshes? Almost like I'd take my multi-part object and make a virtual mould/impression of it?

That way I could then add some volume to it and print it. Yes, I'd lose a little bit of detail (overhangs would no longer exist) but at this point I'd say these are acceptable casualties. I've spent tens of hours on this trying to manually join the bits so far. As a side note - remeshing doesn't work because some of the meshes have 0 thickness and have holes in them.

[image: My cursed model]

For the eagle-eyed among you: yes, this is Los Santos from GTA V.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plane on top of your scene, subdivide it a lot, turn on Face snapping with the option "Project individual elements" turned on, go to top ortographic view, edit mode, select all vertices, press G and Enter, to snap every vertex on top of the original scene.

In my fast example 700K vertices were used, then reduced to 70K with a decimate modifier.

[image]